# request sourceIP for kubernetes webhook server deployed outside of cluster

Tags: kubernetes

When a webhook server is deployed outside a cluster;

- incoming kubectl request that gets validated by the control plane and pulls up the webhookconfiguration
- the webhookconfiguration is pointing to an external server name `external.example.org`
- is the control plane making this request, hence the sourceIP or is the kubelet client attempting to modify the resource being redirected, and hence the sourceIP?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/#webhook-request-and-response